# Get fileName property of PharFileInfo Object

Tags: php, properties, filenames

I have a PharData object and I want to get an array of filenames inside.

```
foreach($PharData as $object){
    print_r($object);
}
```

returns

> PharFileInfo Object
> (
> [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => phar://C:/.../arch.tar/pmnt.csv
> [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => pmnt.csv
> )
> ...

How do I get fileName property? Tried $object->fileName but it says no such property. "Echo $object" gives pathName but I don't want to parse it for filename if there's easier way

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
$object->getFilename();
```

Comment: You would have seen that you must use `->getFileName()` if you read the manual. There is no need for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$info = new SplFileInfo('phar://C:/.../arch.tar/pmnt.csv');//your path to the file.
var_dump($info->getFilename());
```

**Reference**
[splfileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getfilename.php)